# How can I return two different database columns, within the same entity class, as a single column with Android Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have an app that uses the Room persistence library.

I have an entity with a layout similar to this:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| ID |     NAME     | 2LETTERCODE | 3LETTERCODE |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | Fred         | FF          |             |
|  2 | Fred, Alt.   |             | FFA         |
|  3 | Bob          | BB          |             |
|  4 | Bob, Alt.    |             | BBA         |
|  5 | George       | GG          |             |
|  6 | George, Alt. |             | GGA         |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
```

This is the entity class:

```
public class Names {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "TwoLetterCode")
    private String twoLetterCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "ThreeLetterCode")
    private String threeLetterCode;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTwoLetterCode() {
        return twoLetterCode;
    }

    public void setTwoLetterCode(String twoLetterCode) {
        this.twoLetterCode= twoLetterCode;
    }

    public String getThreeLetterCode() {
        return threeLetterCode;
    }

    public void setThreeLetterCode(String threeLetterCode) {
        this.threeLetterCode= threeLetterCode;
    }
}
```

What I would like is the ability to have a combined "virtual" column in the entity class named `code` that would produce something like this:

```
+----+--------------+------+
| ID |     NAME     | CODE |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 | Fred         | FF   |
|  2 | Fred, Alt.   | FFA  |
|  3 | Bob          | BB   |
|  4 | Bob, Alt.    | BBA  |
|  5 | George       | GG   |
|  6 | George, Alt. | GGA  |
+----+--------------+------+
```

So that I could use queries like,

```
SELECT * FROM Names WHERE code = 'FF';
```

which would give me row #1 as a `Names` object? And the following query,

```
SELECT * FROM Names WHERE code = 'FFA';
```

would give me row #2 as a `Names` object ... and so on and so on.

Is there a way to do this, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Do you want this "ability" to work for updation purposes? Or is it just for reading purposes?

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury I'm not sure what you are asking. The original app had just the 3-letter codes, I had to add the 2-letter codes to make it compatible with a new feature. Lots of places in the code use `getName()`, so I guess my answer is "for backwards compatibility".

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to be worried about creating a new virtual table when you can actually run an `OR` query instead. I think you can do something like the following.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE 2LETTERCODE = :code OR 3LETTERCODE = :code")
public List<Names> getCode(int code);
```

Comment: At one point in my code, I iterate through all Names objects and generate a `HashMap` of `code` to `Names` objects like this: `nameCodesHashMap.put(names.getCode(), names);`.

Comment: Then I would like to recommend changing the query in the `getCode` function as I stated above. Then populate your `HashMap` based on the data that you have.

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the `Names` entity?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1: Using the OR in Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE 2LETTERCODE = :code OR 3LETTERCODE = :code")
public List<Names> getNamesByCode(String code);
```

**Approach 2: Using two different methods**

In DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE 2LETTERCODE = :code)
public List<Names> getNamesBy2LetterCode(String code);

@Query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE 3LETTERCODE = :code)
public List<Names> getNamesBy3LetterCode(String code);
```

In Calling Class (Repository/ViewModel/Activity):

```
public List<Names> getNamesByCode(String code){
    if (code.length()==2) return dao.getNamesBy2LetterCode(code);
    else return getNamesBy3LetterCode(code);
}
```

Make sure you're handling database operations in any thread other than the Main (or UI) Thread